# Android Firemonkey app with 5 inch screen

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

My question is addressed to Embarcadero FM/Dephi developpers.
My Android 64bit App "Hello World" (only one label and close Button) inlcudes 10, 7 and 5 inch view.
But on 5 inch device (smartphone) only 7 inch view appears.
I must set something in Manifest file?
Thanks.

Comment: Design you UI in such a way that the elements work on any screen size. That means you work from the center of your form, not from the top left as you would do when programming for Windows.

Comment: There is nothing you can add in the manifest. Delphi has its own calculation and list of devices and their attributes can be found in `System.Android.Devices` It seems that largest phone size is defined as 1708x960 and newer phones have larger side 1920 and more so Dephi decides it is a tablet and not a phone.

Comment: You can probably tweak devices definition in `System.Android.Devices` to get better matches.